# Underset under subscript in align environment

Tags: align, underbrace

How do you go about getting the `\underset` text to show up below an equation that has a subscript?  The current code that I have produces this output:

[image]
**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\tiny{
\begin{align*}
\hspace*{4.65cm}
C(s) & =\dfrac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{s(s^{2}+2\zeta\omega_{n}s+\omega^{2}_{n})}\\
c(t) & = 1-\dfrac{e^{-\zeta\omega_{n}t}}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}\cos\left(\omega_{n}\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}t-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}\right)\right)\\[0.2cm]
& = 1-\dfrac{e^{-\zeta\omega_{n}t}}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}\sin\left(\omega_{n}\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}t+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}{\zeta}\right)\right)\\
M_{P_{t}} & = 1 + e^{\frac{-\zeta\pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}}\hspace*{0.5cm} \fbox{$T_{p}=\frac{\pi}{\omega_{n}\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}=\frac{\pi}{\omega_{d}}$}\\
\underset{(\delta=5\%)}T_{s}& \cong\frac{3}{\zeta\omega_{n}}
\end{align*}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put braces around the entire construct that you want to have above/below in `\underset` if it contains more than one token.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \underset{(\delta=5\%)}{T_s} \cong\frac{3}{\zeta\omega_n}
\]

\end{document}
```